# How to use "pandas json normalize" to convert values as it is (as string)?

Tags: json, pandas, json-deserialization, json-serialization, json-normalize

with some data,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "data": [
        {"a":1},
        {"b":2.1}
    ]
 })
       data
0  {'a': 1}
1  {'b': 2.1}
```

expanding the dictionary in the column using `.json_normalize`:

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['data'])

     a    b
0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  2.1
```

How could those values be represented the same as the original data like below:

```
     a    b
0    1  NaN
1  NaN  2.1
```

One dummy solution appears to be to add a string like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "data": [
        {"a":1},
        {"b":2.1},
        {"a": "dummy"}
    ]
 })
```

then

```
pd.json_normalize(df['data'])
       a    b
0      1  NaN
1    NaN  2.1
2  dummy  NaN
```

what would be some smarter solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
pd.json_normalize(
    df["data"].apply(lambda x: {key: str(value) for key, value in x.items()})
)

# Output in Jupyter cell
     a    b
0    1  NaN
1  NaN  2.1
```